# How to Make a Script or Simple Program to Download File a from a Website on Windows 10?

Tags: windows, windows-10, command-line, powershell, cmd.exe

I was Wondering if you tell me how to make a Script or Simple Program to Download a File a from a password protected Website HTTP website on Windows 10. I want the script to use built in windows tools such as Windows Powershell, Command Prompt, or Wscript. The file extension for the file is .notebook . I am running Windows 10 Home. Thank you, hope you can help me.

Comment: Do you know how to program?

Comment: Kind of,  I have made simple batch programs and wscripts.

Comment: Do you have the password? You should look into "Windows Subsystem for Linux" and wget probably.

Comment: I saw examples online of people who used windows powershell and wscript to download a file from a website without a password but they did not say how to download a file from a website with a password or their directions were not clear enough.

Comment: Skip WSL, just install wget for Windows.

Comment: Jack, it would probably be a good idea to rewrite your question now that you and we have a better idea what you are actually asking. For instance, you would write the question to be about using wget in Windows to download a file from a site that requires password authentication, or about alternative methods such as Powershell.

Answer (score 2):

Windows 10 comes with PowerShell v5/v5.1 containing the
iwr/[Invoke-WebRequest](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-webrequest?view=powershell-5.1) cmdlet which allows exactly that (albeit at a learning curve).

See example 2 in the referencend link which logins to facebook.

Comment: Thank you. I read section 2, but I how do I tell Powershell to download the .notebook file after I logged in the website.

Comment: Examine what you get back from the url by piping variable content to `|gm` = `|Get-Member` there might be a downloadable link contained (example 3)

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that I found the direct link to download the file, so if I just copy and paste that into a web browser I can download the file that way. Is there a way to download the file using that link?

Comment: Use another iwr with `-outfile` parameter or [read this](https://blog.jourdant.me/post/3-ways-to-download-files-with-powershell)

Comment: @Jack that would make the question totally different & easy to solve by googling around